# Why is null not in(1,2,3) false

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it expected that when I test if a null value is **not** in a list, the result is always false.

That is:

```
 select 'Hello world' where null not in(1,2,3);
```

Don't select anything, because null not in(1,2,3) is false.

I don't understand this, because the list(1,2,3) don't contain any undefined values(null) so I would expect the null not in(1,2,3) to be true. So why is it false?

Comment: Null is "unknown", it might as well be `1` - we don't know. So we don't know whether the unknown value is in the list and get null (unknown) as result. Makes sense when you look at it this way. [Implementation details for Postgres.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517899/not-in-in-postgresql-not-working/19528722#19528722)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually `null not in (1,2,3)` returns `null`, not `false`, but it works *like* false a `where` clause (since it's not `true`).

Null comparisons `(a = null)`, etc. always return `null`, and since `null not in (1,2,3)` is essentially the same as:

`NOT (null = 1 OR null = 2 OR null = 3)`

The return value will be `null`.  Your best bet is to do explicit null checks and handle those cases separately.

Side note: `NULL in (null, 1, 2, 3)` will return `null` as well since `null = null` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Null is always a special case in SQL. See

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-comparison.html

> The ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown")
>   when either input is null.

So `Null not In (...) will wield Null`

You can always use a CASE WHEN to bypass this behavior. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: And since the result is unknown, the condition is false, and nothing gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `NULL` into Boolean logic you can actually end up with three values: `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `UNKNOWN`...

In your where clause you end up with an `UNKNOWN`, and no which evaluates as false and so... no records. If you did this:

```
WHERE NULL in (1,2,3,NULL)
```

You would, again, get an 'Unknown' and no records.

In other words, `NULL` is not a value that can be evaluated, it's more like a state of a record.